# Proof of frustum surface area

Tags: geometry

I found a [proof](https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-of-formulas/derivation-of-formula-for-lateral-area-of-a-right-circular-cone) for surface area of a conical frustum and I do not understand the first proportion from which everything else is derived. Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the right triangle $VOB$ is similar to the right triangle $A'AB$ ($OB$ and $O'A'$ are coplanar and both perpendicular to $VO$), it follows that
$$\frac{L_1}{R}=\frac{|VB|}{|OB|}=\frac{|A'B|}{|AB|}=\frac{L}{R-r}.$$

[image]

Comment: @MichaelMunta Is it clear now? Any further doubt?